# Get specific part of dynamic string in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**SAMPLE**

I have string like:

```
AA=Item01,ZZ=Item111,ZZ=Item2,ZZ=Item3333,ZZ=Item4,ZZ=Item55
```

**EXPLANATION**

`AA=` and `ZZ=` are static and always count of `AA=` is 1 and count of `ZZ=` is 5.

All `Item*` are dynamic and their lengths are dynamic.

**WHAT I NEED**

I need to select `Item2` from that string. How can I achieve It?

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried to use `RIGHT`, `LEFT`, `LEN`, `CHARINDEX` to detect `=`, but can't achieve It far away (incorrect syntax)...

---

*NOTE: I know that comma separated strings is terrible practice, but I can't avoid It, customer provide us string like this.*

Comment: Sure, the customer provides you strings like this. But *why do you send them to the database*? Do the parsing in your client code, and use normalized data in the database.

Comment: @Luaan I'm not responsible for that, I can't do nothing with that. I'm working only with SQL queries.

Comment: How "dynamic" are these items? Are *all* characters possible within them e.g. if `ZZ`, `=`, `,` are all possible values, how are they escaped or otherwise demarcated as being part of an `Item`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever possible characters are `A-Z`, `1-9` and `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your items values can't contain `ZZ` and `,ZZ` patterns (so they can be considered as real delimiters) you can do it using bunch of `charindex` and `substring`:

```
declare @src nvarchar(max), @Start_Position int, @End_Position int
select @src = 'AA=Item0,ZZ=Item1,ZZ=Item2,ZZ=Item3,ZZ=Item4,ZZ=Item5'

select @Start_Position = charindex('ZZ', @src, charindex('ZZ', @src) + 1) + 3
select @End_Position = charindex(',ZZ', @src, @Start_Position)

select substring(@src, @Start_Position, @End_Position - @Start_Position)
```

Explanation:

1. Find occurence of first `ZZ` in the string: `charindex('ZZ', @src)`
2. Find occurence of next `ZZ` starting from position of first `ZZ` and add three characters - it will be position where `Item2` starts.
3. Find occurence of `,ZZ` characters starting from position determined in previous step - it will be bosition where `Item2` ends.
4. Do substring.

Comment: This assumes that no `Item` value can contain the sequence `ZZ` nor `,`. This may be the case, but it's a fairly large assumption.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, I suppose OP's note "*always count of AA= is 1 and count of ZZ= is 5*" can be considered as "there are no `ZZ` in the items values"

Comment: @AndyKorneyev That's a pretty big assumption. Perhaps you should add it to your answer?

Comment: @Luaan well, you're right. I've added this assumption for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @src nvarchar(max)
set @src = 'AA=Item0,ZZ=Item1,ZZ=Item2,ZZ=Item3,ZZ=Item4,ZZ=Item5'
select item from [dbo].[SplitString](@src,',') where item like '%item2%'
```

### User defined function

[image]

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[SplitString]    Script Date: 15-01-2016 18:13:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(   
    @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
    Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

    SET @StartIndex = 1
    IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
    BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
    END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: It should return only `Item2` without `ZZ=`

Answer (score 1):

This function will allow you to search for elements in different positions.
Notice that there is only a minimum of slow string manipulating in the syntax:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[f_find_element]
(
  @elementno int,
  @var varchar(max),
  @searchtxt varchar(20)
) RETURNS varchar(max)
as
BEGIN
SELECT @searchtxt += '=', @var = ',=' + @var + ',' +@searchtxt + '='
DECLARE @pos int = 0
;WITH N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f)
SELECT top (@elementno) 
 @pos = CHARINDEX(@searchtxt, @var, @pos + 2)
FROM tally

RETURN
  STUFF(SUBSTRING(@var, @pos, 
  NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @var, @pos + 2), 0) - @pos), 1, LEN(@searchtxt), '')
END
```

Here are some examples of its use.

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max)
  ='AA=Item01,ZZ=Item111,ZZ=Item2,ZZ=Item3333,ZZ=Item4,ZZ=Item55,ZZZ=4'

SELECT element, searchtxt, [dbo].[f_find_element](element, @var, searchtxt) foundvalue
FROM 
  (values(1, 'ZZZ'),(2, 'ZZZ'),
  (2, 'ZZ'),(1, 'AA'),(2, 'AA')) x(element, searchtxt)
```

Result(NULL is returned for the foundvalue, when the element doesn't exist on that position):

```
element searchtxt  foundvalue
1       ZZZ        4
2       ZZZ        NULL
2       ZZ         Item2
1       AA         Item01
2       AA         NULL
```

Comment: Thank for an answer, is it possible to edit function that It searched from right to left? (With your sample data that I should use `dbo.[fn_splitfunction](4, col, "ZZ")`) and It returned me `Item2`

Comment: t-clausen.dk maybe could you explain a bit how does this function Works? Thank you again!